# Mocking custom Object using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am using Mockito to mock some custom objects but I assuming it is not doing what I am intending to do. It throws NPE. I want to know if this is the right way to mock an object.

Code under test

```
ITransformer transformer = new SendDocumentsRESTTransformer();
ITransformerResult result = transformer.transformRequest(args);
```

JUnit test case

```
private ITransformer transformer;

@Before
public void setUP(){
  transformer = mock(ITransformer.class);
}

@Test
public void testSendDocuments() throws Exception {
    AppContext.setApplicationContext( applicationContext );

    DocusignRESTProvider docusignRestProvider = new DocusignRESTProvider();
    docusignRestProvider.setLoggingHandler( iloggingHandler );
    docusignRestProvider.setDocumentManager( iDocumentManager );
    docusignRestProvider.setConfiguration( iProviderConfiguration );

    iClientUserDto.setActive( Boolean.TRUE );
    iClientUserDto.setUserName( "GW_SYS_USER" );
    iClientUserDto.setPassword( "GWPASSWORD" );

    when( args.getClientUserDto()).thenReturn( iClientUserDto );
    when( transformer.transformRequest(args)).thenReturn( transformerResult );

    docusignRestProvider.sendDocuments( iClientUserDto, iDocumentSet );
```

Comment: What you are intending to do ? what is the specific issue? any exceptions?

Comment: I just edited my question. It throws NPE and I am assuming the mocking mechanism is not working.

Comment: Which line causes the problem?

Comment: What is `args` here?  It needs to be a mock if you're going to call `when` on it.

Comment: This is all about ITransformer Object. I am mockign args.

Comment: Where in your code are you mocking `args`?  I can't see it.

Comment: Could you please share the `NPE` with us, it would give more info where exact it happened. + It's unclear who calls `transformer.transformRequest(args)` , probably somewhere inside `docusignRestProvider. sendDocuments` but I didn't see reference passed to provider.

Comment: Actually, I suspect that the problem is that your code under test is making a new `ITransformer`, instead of using the mocked one.  You really need to inject the mocked `ITransformer` somehow.  If that's the case [my article here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mocking-Object-Creation) may give you some ideas.